# SQL shell (psql) permission denied

Tags: postgresql, psql

Before i ask you a question please understand if my question is not well asked. This is my first time using psql. Well, i tried to start the server with shell and there isn't any other databases as you see and they are all default. However it doesn't ask me for password and it occured an error as you see in the code. what do i have to do to fix this issue?

```
Server [localhost]:
Database [postgres]:
Port [5432]:
Username [postgres]:
find: /c/pagefile.sys: Permission denied
```

Comment: Start `psql` directly from the command line, don't use the `bat` file provided by the EnterpriseDB installer. Also: starting `psql` does not "start the server" - it merely starts the default SQL client

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment and i appreciate so so much it worked. Please have a lovely day, thank you so much again.

Answer (score 0):

Just open sqlshell in administrator. My problem solved by this.